# Iterate through a site relative path to find files (ASP.NET MVC 3)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, web-applications

I have a folder in my web application (ASP.NET MVC 3) which contains a set of images. I want to use a foreach loop to iterate through the folder to get the site relative paths which I can then append to an image tag.

Example

```
<div class="slides">
@foreach(string file in ?????)
{
    <img src="@file" alt="filename without extension">
}
</div>
```

How do I do this?

NOTE: my current foreach loop is trying to look through a physical path and returns this error

```
Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Content\Images\Photography\Slides\'.
```

Comment: This kind of activity should be done at the controller or perhaps even the model level, no? i.e. pass an ienumerable of uri's to the view

Comment: @ChristopherBales, I see your point but regardless, this does not solve the issue.

Comment: Check that the folder exists and that the current process has rights to read it. After you get it to work, follow the advice @ChristopherBales gave you.

Comment: @w0lf, is there no equivalent of Directory.GeFiles for web folders?

Comment: Did you try HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath?

Comment: @lkaso, yes I have solved it...kinda

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you'd like to enumerate the files in a path relative to the website's root, you could do:

```
@foreach (var file in 
    Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/Photography/Slides")))
```